# Given a radius, calculate Bezier curve

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

For a given radius, theta, and position, can you calculate a Bezier curve?

Comment: Perhaps if you give the definition of Bezier curve.

Comment: Bézier curves cannot represent circles; they can approximate them however. Rational quadratics are needed here.

Comment: @J.M...can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ J.M. is not a mathematician sir, if we put in vertices of a regular polygon say $n>12,$ then also we dont get a circle of constant curvature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In section 2.11 on p. 27 of the following there is a description of how to create a bezier curve that exactly represents an arc.

https://web.archive.org/web/20170830004521/http://www.tsplines.com/resources/class_notes/Bezier_curves.pdf